# Improve select statement performance

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-tuning

I'm with an Select performance issue, how can I make this SQL more efficient?

```
SELECT
 O.DT_OCORRENCIA,
 S.NU_SMP,
 CLI.NM_APELIDO CLI,
 TRANS.NM_ENTIDADE TRANS,
 TPO.DS_TIPO_OCORRENCIA,
 O.DS_OCORRENCIA,
 REPLACE(FNC_RETORNA_MOTORISTAS(S.CD_SMP), '<br>', ';') AS NOME_MOTORISTA,
 OG.DS_NOME AS DS_NOME_ORIGEM,
 DG.DS_NOME AS DS_NOME_DESTINO,
 U.NM_LOGIN AS DS_USUARIO_OCORRENCIA,
 CASE
   WHEN O.CD_USUARIO_INFORMOU = 717 THEN
    'NAO'
   ELSE
    'SIM'
 END FL_MANUAL,
 CASE
   WHEN (O.FL_ENVIOU_EMAIL_CLIENTE = 'S' OR O.FL_ENVIOU_EMAIL_TRANSP = 'S') THEN
    'SIM'
   ELSE
    'NÃO'
 END ENVIOU_EMAIL,
 DECODE(O.NU_LOCAL_OCORRENCIA,
        '1',
        'Origem',
        '2',
        'Em transito',
        '3',
        'Alvos',
        '4',
        'Indiferente') DS_LOCAL_OCORRENCIA,
 TOPER.DS_TIPO_OPERACAO
  FROM TB_SMP S
 INNER JOIN TB_OCORRENCIA O
    ON O.CD_SMP = S.CD_SMP
 INNER JOIN TB_TIPO_OCORRENCIA TPO
    ON O.CD_TIPO_OCORRENCIA = TPO.CD_TIPO_OCORRENCIA
  LEFT JOIN TB_TIPO_OPERACAO TOPER
    ON TOPER.CD_TIPO_OPERACAO = S.CD_TIPO_OPERACAO
  LEFT JOIN TB_USUARIO U
    ON U.CD_USUARIO = O.CD_USUARIO_INFORMOU
  LEFT JOIN TB_ENTIDADE CLI
    ON CLI.CD_ENTIDADE = S.CD_ENTIDADE_CLIENTE
  LEFT JOIN TB_ENTIDADE TRANS
    ON TRANS.CD_ENTIDADE = S.CD_ENTIDADE_TRANSPORTADOR
  LEFT JOIN TB_PONTO_GEOREFERENCIADO OG
    ON OG.CD_PONTO_GEOREFERENCIADO = S.CD_PONTO_GEO_ORIGEM
  LEFT JOIN TB_PONTO_GEOREFERENCIADO DG
    ON (S.CD_PONTO_GEO_DESTINO IS NULL AND
       DG.CD_PONTO_GEOREFERENCIADO =
       FNC_GET_ULTIMA_ENTREGA_PONTO(S.CD_SMP))
    OR (S.CD_PONTO_GEO_DESTINO IS NOT NULL AND
       DG.CD_PONTO_GEOREFERENCIADO = S.CD_PONTO_GEO_DESTINO)

 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM TB_TIPO_OCORRENCIA T
         WHERE T.CD_TIPO_OCORRENCIA = O.CD_TIPO_OCORRENCIA)

   AND S.DT_CADASTRO BETWEEN to_date('21/04/2014', 'dd/MM/yyyy') AND to_date('09/06/2014', 'dd/MM/yyyy')
   AND O.DT_OCORRENCIA BETWEEN to_date('10/05/2014','dd/MM/yyyy') AND to_date('20/05/2014','dd/MM/yyyy')
   AND S.cd_tipo_operacao in
       (-1, 27, 11, 13, 37, 6, 7, 21, 12, 36, 28, 4, 5)

-- order by using linq?
 ORDER BY CLI.NM_APELIDO,
          TRANS.NM_APELIDO,
          O.DT_OCORRENCIA,
          DS_TIPO_OCORRENCIA
```

Here goes my execution plan:
[image: explain plan]

PS.: I don't know nothing about sql tunnig :(

Comment: You can remove `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM TB_TIPO_OCORRENCIA T
         WHERE T.CD_TIPO_OCORRENCIA = O.CD_TIPO_OCORRENCIA)` as you already INNER JOIN `TB_OCORRENCIA` and `TB_TIPO_OCORRENCIA` earlier.

Comment: Doesn't Oracle store time as part of the `DATE` type?  Then you want to avoid [the inclusive upper-bound found in `BETWEEN`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (yes, this applies to _all_ systems with a continuous-range type).  I'm curious whether you could switch `DS_TIPO_OCORRENCIA` in the `ORDER BY` to `O.DS_OCORRENCIA` (same-table usually means better likelihood of index use).

Answer (score 0):

You can move some of the WHERE conditions to the JOIN conditions as you are doing an INNER JOIN on these tables, as below. Then, you would be operating on a smaller data set when you come to the LEFT JOIN conditions.

```
SELECT
 O.DT_OCORRENCIA,
 S.NU_SMP,
 CLI.NM_APELIDO CLI,
 TRANS.NM_ENTIDADE TRANS,
 TPO.DS_TIPO_OCORRENCIA,
 O.DS_OCORRENCIA,
 REPLACE(FNC_RETORNA_MOTORISTAS(S.CD_SMP), '<br>', ';') AS NOME_MOTORISTA,
 OG.DS_NOME AS DS_NOME_ORIGEM,
 DG.DS_NOME AS DS_NOME_DESTINO,
 U.NM_LOGIN AS DS_USUARIO_OCORRENCIA,
 CASE
   WHEN O.CD_USUARIO_INFORMOU = 717 THEN
    'NAO'
   ELSE
    'SIM'
 END FL_MANUAL,
 CASE
   WHEN (O.FL_ENVIOU_EMAIL_CLIENTE = 'S' OR O.FL_ENVIOU_EMAIL_TRANSP = 'S') THEN
    'SIM'
   ELSE
    'NÃO'
 END ENVIOU_EMAIL,
 DECODE(O.NU_LOCAL_OCORRENCIA,
        '1',
        'Origem',
        '2',
        'Em transito',
        '3',
        'Alvos',
        '4',
        'Indiferente') DS_LOCAL_OCORRENCIA,
 TOPER.DS_TIPO_OPERACAO
  FROM TB_SMP S
 INNER JOIN TB_OCORRENCIA O
    ON O.CD_SMP = S.CD_SMP
   AND S.DT_CADASTRO BETWEEN to_date('21/04/2014', 'dd/MM/yyyy') AND to_date('09/06/2014', 'dd/MM/yyyy')
   AND O.DT_OCORRENCIA BETWEEN to_date('10/05/2014','dd/MM/yyyy') AND to_date('20/05/2014','dd/MM/yyyy')
   AND S.cd_tipo_operacao in
       (-1, 27, 11, 13, 37, 6, 7, 21, 12, 36, 28, 4, 5)
 INNER JOIN TB_TIPO_OCORRENCIA TPO
    ON O.CD_TIPO_OCORRENCIA = TPO.CD_TIPO_OCORRENCIA
  LEFT JOIN TB_TIPO_OPERACAO TOPER
    ON TOPER.CD_TIPO_OPERACAO = S.CD_TIPO_OPERACAO
  LEFT JOIN TB_USUARIO U
    ON U.CD_USUARIO = O.CD_USUARIO_INFORMOU
  LEFT JOIN TB_ENTIDADE CLI
    ON CLI.CD_ENTIDADE = S.CD_ENTIDADE_CLIENTE
  LEFT JOIN TB_ENTIDADE TRANS
    ON TRANS.CD_ENTIDADE = S.CD_ENTIDADE_TRANSPORTADOR
  LEFT JOIN TB_PONTO_GEOREFERENCIADO OG
    ON OG.CD_PONTO_GEOREFERENCIADO = S.CD_PONTO_GEO_ORIGEM
  LEFT JOIN TB_PONTO_GEOREFERENCIADO DG
    ON (S.CD_PONTO_GEO_DESTINO IS NULL AND
       DG.CD_PONTO_GEOREFERENCIADO =
       FNC_GET_ULTIMA_ENTREGA_PONTO(S.CD_SMP))
    OR (S.CD_PONTO_GEO_DESTINO IS NOT NULL AND
       DG.CD_PONTO_GEOREFERENCIADO = S.CD_PONTO_GEO_DESTINO)
-- order by using linq?
 ORDER BY CLI.NM_APELIDO,
          TRANS.NM_APELIDO,
          O.DT_OCORRENCIA,
          DS_TIPO_OCORRENCIA;
```

Adding indexes on the columns that are used for joining / filtering would help as well, especially on

```
TB_SMP.DT_CADASTRO
TB_SMP.cd_tipo_operacao
TB_OCORRENCIA.DT_OCORRENCIA
TB_ENTIDADE.CD_ENTIDADE
```

Comment: ... I generally recommend only moving those conditions to a `JOIN` that directly reference that table.  When the table is in the `FROM` clause, leave conditions that reference only that table in the `WHERE` clause.  For the `BETWEEN` condition, the RDBMS is likely doing this automatically, so won't (likely) gain any benefits in this case.

Comment: For inner joins, it should make a difference whether the conditions are in the `on` clause or the `where` clause.  The Oracle optimizer does a pretty good job.